Can I tap a permanent for mana multiple times with multiple copies of an untap spell on the stack?
Let's say I have Thousand-Year Storm with a few triggers (or some other copy ability), then I cast Dramatic Reversal (or similar) can I tap my mana rocks between each resolve of Dramatic Reversal? Say if I had three copies, and an Empowered Autogenerator, could I untap and retap it each time, giving me a glorious bounty of sweet, sweet mana?

Yes, you can do this.
Spells and abilities on the stack resolve one at at time, and each player gets a chance to take actions in between each resolution. After each copy of Dramatic Reversal resolves, you can activate any number of mana abilities (and take other actions) before the next copy resolves. The Timing and Priority rules in section 117 lay out the system of timing that governs interactions like this. In particular, the most relevant rules are the following:

117.1. Unless a spell or ability is instructing a player to take an action, which player can take actions at any given time is determined by a system of priority. The player with priority may cast spells, activate abilities, and take special actions.
[...]
117.3. Which player has priority is determined by the following rules:

117.3a The active player receives priority at the beginning of most steps and phases, after any turn-based actions (such as drawing a card during the draw step; see rule 703) have been dealt with and abilities that trigger at the beginning of that phase or step have been put on the stack. No player receives priority during the untap step. Players usually don’t get priority during the cleanup step (see rule 514.3).

117.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.

117.3c If a player has priority when they cast a spell, activate an ability, or take a special action, that player receives priority afterward.

117.3d If a player has priority and chooses not to take any actions, that player passes. If any mana is in that player’s mana pool, they announce what mana is there. Then the next player in turn order receives priority.


117.4. If all players pass in succession (that is, if all players pass without taking any actions in between passing), the spell or ability on top of the stack resolves or, if the stack is empty, the phase or step ends.


Amazing, thank you! To infinity, and beyond!!!

@NotDead you can accept answers by clicking the tick sign on the left of the answer below the voting. this makes clear that this question has been answered/solved. have a great day! :)

As I understood the situation, the ability to do this had a lot to do with the banning of Wilderness Reclamation in Pioneer (and formerly in Standard, IIRC). With a reasonable assortment of draw spells taking advantage of the extra mana, it was very easy to snowball into multiple copies of the enchantment.
